# The format of Date is invalid

Tags: php, mysql, date, yii

I have an array like:

```
 $holiday = array(array('h_date' => $new_year, 'd_name' => 'New Year'),
    array('h_date' => $memorial_day, 'd_name' => 'Memorial Day')
 foreach($holiday as $holidays){
 $date = $holidays["h_date"];
 $name = $holidays["d_name"]
```

when i save in mysql database

```
 $model = new Holiday();
 $model->holiday_date = $date;
 $model->display_name = $name;
 $model->save();
```

when i write

```
 $model->save(false);
```

**value successfully saved but without "false" data not saved** 
when saw validation error than error:

```
 Array ( [holiday_date] => Array ( [0] => The format of Holiday Date is invalid.))
```

we use

```
protected function beforeSave(){
    if(parent::beforeSave()){
        $this->holiday_date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->holiday_date));

        return TRUE;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your field of saving is char change it to date

Comment: Sir, Please more detail.

Comment: In mysql Change field type from char to date

Comment: Sir, Already Date format in MySql

Comment: Either don't send the data in case doing is provided or set the default as 00-00-0000

Comment: can u post the validation rules for the model

Comment: Thanks a lots, I put validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the date format on beforeValidate or either change the validation rules for your `holiday_date` attribute, as beforeSave is executed after the validation is passed.

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        $this->holiday_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->holiday_date));
    }
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. when i cahnge in validation rules date format saved but in this case no data saved

Comment: Can you post the validation rules of your model?

Comment: Yes, we can create own validation rule in Yii framework.http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Comment: I was asking for the validation rules for your attribute ´holiday_date´. Anyway, if you have solved it, you should post an answer and accept it so the issue it's closed.

Comment: what *type* is $this->holiday_date? a DateTime or a string?